# Linking to external CSS and JS inside your Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, static-resources, lightning-connect

Is it at all possible to have `<link href="http://jacobraccuia.com/styles.css">`inside your Visualforce page and have it work when clicking the `http://cs14.salesforce.com/apex/visualforce_page`?

That way i can make tons of CSS changes without having to reupload or repackage files.

It works perfectly when I make the site a public domain but inside Salesforce it doesn't.  It seems like I'm going to have to re-zip and reference as a static resource whenever I want to demo or repackage or something.  The other problem is that one of the components requires log-in, which is not something I have set up...

I haven't fooled around with the Eclipse IDE, but maybe that is the way to go.

edit: here is the top of my code!

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false"  standardStyleSheets="false" controller="Boardroom_Home_Jacob">
<head>
    <apex:stylesheet value="http://jacobraccuia.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="http://jacobraccuia.com/sf_styles.css" />
</head>
```

edit 2:  adding https:// seemed to work perfectly in Firefox, but in Chrome....
`(failed)
net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

Comment: Don't forget: The URL for your page is http://cs14.salesforce.com/apex/visualforce_page, and if it's a site, then the website won't be cs14.salesforce.com - it will have some other subdomain.

Comment: @DavidSchach yes it is!

Comment: See answer below: Remove head tags. Not intuitive for "real" web developers, but that's a quirk of Visualforce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can absolutely do that. But use this markup:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

I'm sure others will answer with style tips, such as working within a Visualforce Component at first, or using a text static resource, but if this way works for you while developing, then go for it.

Just saw the edit to the code above. Don't put the VF tags in  tags. Just put them "naked." Don't use head tags at all here.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false"  standardStyleSheets="false" controller="Boardroom_Home_Jacob">
<apex:stylesheet value="http://jacobraccuia.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<apex:stylesheet value="http://jacobraccuia.com/sf_styles.css" />
</apex:page>
```

That's it. Should do it. Although if you're using https for your site, it may want secure listings for the stylesheets.

Comment: this didn't work - nothing changed!

Comment: That's impossible. This is exactly how I - and everyone else - links to stylesheets when they are externally hosted. Can you please post the code to your page so we can see if something else is interfering?

Comment: I updated the code above

Comment: Still nothing!  I moved them outside / moved the head tags. I noticed that only like one of the external links at all works, and that is an image.  I tried removing the HTTP: as well.  Note: they work on the external site still.

Comment: See my edit. Please debug this using a regular Visualforce page, without going through the Site - once it works there, you can put the page into a Site and go from there.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work.  I'm not sure what to do anymore!

Comment: Okay, let's take a step back. Can you navigate to http://cs14.salesforce.com/apex/visualforce_page and see the page at all? What does it show? If you put some naked text into the VF page, does it show in the browser?

Comment: Yes.  It shows the HTML I have there, and also links to a controller that pulls some stuff from multiple objects.  There are no styles set AT all, but there is an image which is externally referenced that DOES load.  Also, ONE of the jquery files, the jquery-min CDN file does load

Comment: If the jquery-min file loads, then the only possibility is that there is something wrong with your sf_styles.css file. Are you trying to override standard styles? Is it meant to be a completely novel UI? Is there perhaps formatting gone wrong? Try the console in Chrome to see what it sees.

Comment: I believe linking to external stylesheets from Salesforce requires that you use HTTPS

Comment: I tried to do http:// and simply //, which http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251128/why-am-i-suddenly-getting-a-blocked-loading-mixed-active-content-issue-in-fire suggested.  I just did https:// and it loaded fine.  I realllly appreciate your help.

Comment: You're very welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted so we can close this out.

Comment: @DavidSchach it's actually still not working.  Well, it works in Firefox but not Chrome

Comment: I had to move the files to a server with a valid SSL certificate

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use the Eclipse Force.com IDE you can download the Zip Editor plug-in and it allows you to edit and save the files (including css & js) in your static resources from inside of eclipse. This makes deployment of CSS and JS way easier and much less time consuming.

Here is the source forge link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/zipeditor/

Comment: I read somewhere that it is a little different in a Mac environment.  I'm hesitating on it, but will likely bite closer to deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting an easy was to deal with zipping, use sublime/mavens mate.  They have a thing called  "resource bundles" so you can edit files while still zipped, then in one step, deploy it back to the server as a static resource.

Besides being a generally awesome text editor.